# How to change files so that when you click on the "load more" button the browser dynamically adds the following entries from the database in the list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How to change files so that when you click on the "load more" button the browser dynamically adds the following entries from the database in the list

index.php

```
<?php
include('pdo.php');
include('item.php');
include('loadMore.php');
?>
<div id="container">
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <div class="single-item" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>">
            <?= $item->show() ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<button id="loadMore">Загрузить ещё...</button>

<script src="/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

item.php

```
<?php
class Item
{
    public $id;
    public $text;

    function __construct($id = null, $text = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->text = $text;
    }


    public function show()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

loadmore.php

```
<?php
$offset = 0;
$limit = 10;
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM credit LIMIT ?, ?');
$statement->bindValue(1, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$data = $statement->fetchAll();
$items = [];
foreach ($data as $item) 
{
    $items[] = new Item($item['id'], $item['tel']);
}
```

pdo.php

```
<?php
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db   = 'test';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

script.js

```
function getMoreItems() {
    var url = "/loadMore.php";
    var data = {
        //
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: 'get',
        success: function (res) {
            //
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //
        }
    });
}
```

How to change files so that when you click on the "load more" button the browser dynamically adds the following entries from the database in the list

I think 2 hours and I can not understand.
Help.(

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusion, I believe you're wondering why your php code in index.php doesn't work properly after you call loadMore.php using ajax.

There's one distinction you need to understand to be capable of developing for the web. The difference between server-side and client-side code.

PHP is a server-side programming language, which means that it only executes on the server. Your server returns html, or json, or text, or anything to the browser and once the response arrives at the browser, you can forget about php code.

Javascript on the other hand is a client side programming language (at least in your case) It executes on the browser.

You basically have two options:

1. To send back some json and loop over it using jQuery, which is the preferable choice, but I fear it requires more work.
2. Send back html and append it to your page, first create a file called async.php

```php
<?php
include('pdo.php');
include('item.php');
include('loadMore.php');
?>

<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <div class="single-item" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>">
        <?= $item->show() ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

in your js add to your success callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: 'get',
    success: function (res) {
        $('#container').append(res);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //
    }
});
```

don't forget `var url = "async.php";`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to attach the buttons `onclick=""` attribute with the ajax-method.

```
<button ... onclick="getMoreItems">...</button>
```

Second, your loadmore.php need to `require_once` the files it depends on:

```
require_once('pdo.php');
require_once('item.php');
```

Third, separate your logic for querying the database to a function in the pdo.php file you can call with the limits as parameters, i.e.

```
function getData($offset = 0, $limit = 10){ 
    //logic 
}
```

You should also always try to use `require_once` or `include_once` to be sure files aren't loaded several times.

Now you can call the function `getData(...)` from index.php before the container div to load up the initial data, remove the include to loadmore.php from index.php, and in loadmore.php write the logic to use the parameters sent from the webpage to get the next chunk of data.

The `data:...` in your ajax needs to pass along the "page" it wants to get, perhaps simply a counter as to how many times you have loaded more. In the loadmore.php script you then just multiply the page by the limit to get the offset.

Return the data as JSON to the ajax, parse the JSON so you can build a new div for each item, then add each div to the container-div using javascript.

Im not going in detail on all topics here, but you at least will know what tutorials to search for on google :)